# Running Apache Atlas standalone

Tags: apache-atlas

I am trying to run Apache Atlas in a standalone fashion on Ubuntu - meaning without having to setup Solr and/or HBase.
What I did (according to the documentation: http://atlas.apache.org/0.8.1/InstallationSteps.html) was cloning the Git repository, build the maven project with embadded HBase an dSolr:

```
mvn clean package -Pdist,embedded-hbase-solr
```

Unpacked the resuting tar.gz file and executed bin/atlas_start.py - without having changed any configuration. To my understanding of the documentatino that should actually start up HBase along with Atlas - right?

The is what I find in logs/applocation.log:

```
2017-11-30 17:14:24,093 INFO  - [main:] ~ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> (Atlas:216)
2017-11-30 17:14:24,093 INFO  - [main:] ~ Server starting with TLS ? false on port 21000 (Atlas:217)
2017-11-30 17:14:24,093 INFO  - [main:] ~ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< (Atlas:218)
2017-11-30 17:14:27,684 INFO  - [main:] ~ No authentication method configured.  Defaulting to simple authentication (LoginProcessor:102)
2017-11-30 17:14:28,527 INFO  - [main:] ~ Logged in user daniel (auth:SIMPLE) (LoginProcessor:77)
2017-11-30 17:14:31,777 INFO  - [main:] ~ Not running setup per configuration atlas.server.run.setup.on.start. (SetupSteps$SetupRequired:189)
2017-11-30 17:14:39,456 WARN  - [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):] ~ Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (ClientCnxn$SendThread:110$
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2017-11-30 17:14:39,594 WARN  - [main:] ~ Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=localhost:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = Connecti$
2017-11-30 17:14:40,593 WARN  - [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):] ~ Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (ClientCnxn$SendThread:110$
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
```

...

```
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2017-11-30 17:14:56,185 WARN  - [main:] ~ Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=localhost:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = Connecti$
2017-11-30 17:14:56,186 ERROR - [main:] ~ ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts (RecoverableZooKeeper:277)
2017-11-30 17:14:56,186 WARN  - [main:] ~ hconnection-0x1dba4e060x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid) (ZKUtil:544)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
```

To me it reads as if no HBase (and Zookeeper) are started by the script.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, meanwhile I figured out the issue. The start script obviously does not execute the script conf/atlas-env.sh which sets some environment variable. Among this are MANAGE_LOCAL_HBASE and MANAGE_LOCAL_SOLR. So if you set those two env vars to true (and set JAVA_HOME properly which is needed for the embedded HBase), then Atlas automatically starts HBase and Solr - and we get a local running instance of Atlas!

Maybe this helps someone who comes across the same issue in future!

Comment: More info here : https://atlas.apache.org/InstallationSteps.html#Installing_.26_Running_Apache_Atlas

Comment: @Daniel can you guide me a bit how to set this up in a windows laptop. For me also the starup atlas_start.py script only starting the atlas server but unable to start hbase and solar.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update March 2021

There are two ways of running apache atlas:

A) Building it from scratch:

1. git clone https://github.com/apache/atlas
2. mvn clean install -DskipTests
3. mvn clean package -Pdist -DskipTests
4. Running `atlas_start.py`:

   ```
   python <atlas-directory>/conf/atlas_start.py
   ```

B) Using [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sburn/apache-atlas):

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  atlas:
    image: sburn/apache-atlas
    container_name: atlas
    ports:
      - "21000:21000"
    volumes:
      - "./bash_script:/app"
    command: bash -exc "/opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/bin/atlas_start.py"
```

```
docker-compose up
```